# Execute node function on server running

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, debugging, node-modules

I've got a node.js server running listening on  6503 port.

I'm trying to execute any function inside my main proccess (app.js in example) using the current values of vars.

In example, i need to be able to execute a function from my command line in order to get the current connections in the server. I'm already running the server as debugging, setting breakpoints, etc. But i need execute a function inside my server using those current values.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

According to comment answers i've tried:

in my app.js:

```
module.exports.a = function() {
console.log("AAAA");
};
```

Then in chrome devtools console:

```
this.a()
```

I got:

> VM276:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.a is not a function
>       at :1:6

Comment: Do you mean you want to call the function in the debugger? "*from my command line*" is unclear.

Comment: Just set a breakpoint to whereever that function is in scope, wait until it halts, and call the function from the devtools console.

Comment: Yes i nedd to run a function from the debugger but without setting a breakpoint. In example, my server is running on production environment and i need to see  the quantity of current connections, so in this case i can't set a breakpoint but i need to run this function and see the console.log()

Comment: Even without a breakpoint, you can just run any code in the devtools console, you just need to make sure that the function you want to call is globally available (or can be `require`d)

Comment: Thanks! this is what i need, however, i've got a function in my app.js, but when i try to execute this on my devtools console it says it's not defined. How to specify it to declare globally?

Comment: Either export it normally (`module.exports`) so that you can `require('app.js')`, or put it on [the `global` object](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you provide an example? Since i've got a single file app.js, should i export it inside app.js? Then from the console i call the function only by its name?

Comment: @Bergi Post updated!

Comment: Why are you using `this.a`? What is `this`? I wrote `require('app.js').a()`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. Is there any way to pass a current var value from the debugger console? i.e: require("app.js").connections(httpServer)

Comment: What do you mean by "current var value"? Everything you want to use needs to be in scope, there's nothing magic about that.

Comment: So if i have a var "b" in a file "test.js" i can make something like require('app.js').myFunc(b) ? (having required previously test.js in my app.js)

Comment: No, if you have a `var` in your module, that variable will be located in the module scope, and you cannot access it from outside. (You'd need to break on a statement that has it in scope to access it from the devtools console).